# How to install memcache on Mavericks? (MAMP)

Tags: php, apache, mamp, homebrew, libmemcache

I have MAMP on my machine, and I would like to install memcache for php, because one of my project throws errors like `Fatal error: Class 'Memcache' not found`.

I installed *X-Code* from appstore, and *libevent*, *memcached*, *libmemcached* with *homebrew*.

Then..

```
cd /tmp; pecl download memcached
gzip -d < memcached-2.2.0.tgz | tar -xvf -
cd memcached-2.2.0; phpize
./configure; make
sudo make install
```

**Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/**

After that I copied memcached.so and memcache.so to my extension_folder:

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/

and added extension = memcached.so to my php.ini.

I still get fatal error.. what's the problem?

Comment: You need to `phpize` with the version of PHP you're building for. Apparently you're `phpizing` with the system default PHP but are using it in MAMP's bundled version.

Comment: I tried it, but I still get errors.

Comment: Same problem for me, even the /Application/MAMP/bin/php/php<version>/bin/phpize fails... What's the problem, how to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to install memcache and memcached on any version MAMP and on any version of php on LINUX/MAC by yourself?**

1. open a terminal
2. install brew:

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

3. > brew install memcached
4. > brew install libmemcached
5. start memchached (daemon) as you whish
   To have launchd start memcached at login:

> ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/memcached/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Then to load memcached now:

> launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist

Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:

> /usr/local/opt/memcached/bin/memcached

6. download the **SAME !!! VERSION** of php source code from php.net what you want to use with MAMP
7. extract to /tmp
8. configure -> make -> make install
9. when "make install" ends you can see **ON THE TERMINAL SCREEN !!!** the paths where the php binary was installed on your system
10. cd that path where your binary located
11. pecl i memcache
12. follow **onscreen !!! instruction** and copy memcache.so
13. if no instruction, which I doubt it then locate **YOUR VERSION** of php extensions directory/no-debug-non-zts... or copy memcache.so to here on MAC

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/**[PHP VERSION YOU
>   USE!!!]**/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613

14. add to php.ini **(the same version you downloaded and using with mamp)** this line: extension=memcache.so;
15. phpinfo(); and check memcached appears.

OK ITS DONE !!! NOW -> have a beer :)